# Generated tags don't load with css

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

I am appending a user entry to a list.

Like:

```
var enterul = document.getElementById('entrylist');
    var entryli = document.createElement("LI");

var entryvalue = document.createTextNode(item.entry);
        entryli.appendChild(entryvalue);
        enterul.appendChild(entryli);
```

It does populate my ul, but not with JQM css, just a regular HTML list.

If I go in html and add a list item like: `<ul><li>Item</li></ul>`
It shows like a jqm list.

`enterul.innerHTML += ...` doesnt work also.

Comment: When are you running this function?

Answer (score 2):

With everything in jQuery Mobile, if you update the markup after it has been rendered, you have to tell jQuery Mobile to re-render the control.  With a list view, you accomplish this with the method call:

```
$('#entryList').listview("refresh");
```

Documentation for this method is given at http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/lists/lists-methods.html